# mongodb node driver connect() ignores connectTimeoutMS (and socketTimeoutMS) settings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using [mongodb node driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) version 4.7.0 (latest at the moment of writing this). I have the following fragment of code to connect to DB:

```
var url = "<my mongodb:// URI>";
var client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
client.connect(
    url,
    {
        connectTimeoutMS: 2000
    },
    <callback function>);
```

So it should timeout if DB doesn't exist after 2 seconds (2000 ms). However, the timeouts takes place at 30s (30000 ms), which I guess is the default for the setting. In other words, it seems that `connectTimeoutMS` is being ignored.

I have also tried with `socketTimeoutMS: 2000` and combining both `connectTimeoutMS: 2000` and `socketTimeoutMS: 2000` and the result is the same.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with how [unified topology](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/#behavioral-changes) works.

You are always considered "connected" by the driver and then under the hood it auto reconnects for you, but if you want to timeout on the initial server selection (e.g. to detect if mongo is down initially), you can do this with [serverSelectionTimeoutMS](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/MongoClientOptions.html#serverSelectionTimeoutMS)

I suspect the other timeout options are honored properly, just deeper down the stack so you don't notice it.